# Period in tooltips?

Tags: desktop-application, tooltips

Should tooltips in a desktop application end with a period? Is proper English required in this case?

Looking forward to any feedback or examples on this.

Thank you!

Comment: You should reference and follow any relevant writing style guides as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is **[Material Design's guide to UX writing](https://material.io/design/communication/writing.html#principles)**

[image]

The rule at most places I've been with dedicated UX Writers is:

- No periods for a single UI string (in any place - tooltip, help text)
- If there's more than one sentence, periods as normally applied

The **general principle** is to mercilessly cut down the amount of words / characters etc, prioritizing brevity.